# Canvas roulette wheel - using background images as each slice

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a roulette wheel created with HTML5 canvas and currently each slice is a plain color generated by using the `fillStyle()`, `beginPath()`, `stroke()`, then `fill()` methods.

I would like to use images that that crop appropriately in the shape of the slice, but I'm not sure how to implement this using `drawImage()`.

Here's the jsfiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/pyD2q/2/**

Any help or resources is appreciated.

Comment: Does it need to be dynamic? otherwise you could make only one picture and use that as background. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YNBxz/2/

Comment: Yes, each slice will have a dynamic image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filling the color in you can use it as a clipping mask instead. For each arc, set clip, draw the image and repeat.

Something like this (untested):

```
for (i = 0; i < s.members.length; i++) {
    angle = s.startAngle + i * s.arc;

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.arc(s.width / 2, s.height / 2, s.outsideRadius, angle, angle + s.arc, false);
    ctx.arc(s.width / 2, s.height / 2, s.insideRadius, angle + s.arc, angle, true);

    ctx.save();   /// store current clip-state
    ctx.clip();   /// set current arc as clipping mask

    ctx.drawImage(someImageArray[i], x, y, width, height);

    ctx.restore(); /// restore clip-state
    ctx.stroke();  /// stroke arc
}
```

You will of course also need to place the images correctly relative to the section and if you want to rotate the image you would need to rotate it at this point.

In that regard I would recommend creating this wheel on an off-screen canvas. This way you only need to draw the off-screen canvas into the main canvas rotated and what have you (saves you the trouble of calculating each angle as well and the performance will be better).